# how are dependencies managed in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, maven, nuget

how are dependencies managed in C# ? For example in java there is maven (pom.xml), and in JS there is npm (package.json), and in C# there is nuget... but  what is the alternative of pom.xml in C# ?

Is that maybe .csproj file ?

Comment: Yeah, in the csproj file, there will be PackageReference tags which references the nuget packages

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The package manager for .NET C# is [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/),

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/what-is-nuget

.NET used to have a package.json file containing the packages for a project, but nowadays the packages are defined right in to the .csproj file. For example:

```cs
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AspNetCore.HealthChecks.Hangfire" Version="6.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="AspNetCore.HealthChecks.SqlServer" Version="6.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="AspNetCore.HealthChecks.System" Version="6.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="AspNetCore.HealthChecks.Uris" Version="6.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="12.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="12.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Hangfire.AspNetCore" Version="1.7.32" />
    <PackageReference Include="Hangfire.Console" Version="1.4.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Hangfire.SqlServer" Version="1.7.32" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="6.0.11" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Packages can be managed right in visual studio by the nuget package manager:

[image]
[image]

Same can be done for the whole solution:
[image]

From the command line you can work with nuget.exe, or dotnet.exe;

```
nuget install Flurl -Version 3.0.6
dotnet add package Flurl --version 3.0.6
```

There are also the nuget package manager console intergrated into visual studio:

[image]

You can select a default project from the dropdown, and then call `Install-Package`.

Generally most library repositories on github have either a link to the package on nuget.org or have a snippet to directly install the package via the nuget package manager console.

For example a random library [flurl](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl) :
[image]

Comment: thank you very much for your detailed answer. where could i see all the specifications of .csproj file? do you maybe have a link for me ? 

By specifications I mean how to define the name and version ,. etc of a project.

Comment: Well the csproj file is part of msbuild, the compiler. Here is some documentation regarding msbuild and the csproj files. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview

Answer (score 1):

As a complement for answer by @sommmen - there is a recent addition to package management in .NET -  [central package management](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/introducing-central-package-management/) which allows to centrally manage package versions in C# solutions via  `Directory.Packages.props` file.